# Ansible install all required Azure modules

Tags: azure, ansible

I'm trying a simple thing like creating a Resource group in Azure via an Ansible Playbook, but I need the Azure Python SDK for it. I can't install the SDK with `pip install azure` because Microsoft doesn't support it anymore, which is completely illogical because Ansible keeps showing `ModuleNotFoundError` errors every time I execute the playbook, and I have to install them all manually...

Any more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking to install Ansible Azure module. So please try the following,

If you already have `python` and `pip` installed, use the command `pip install ansible[azure]`, to install Azure modules.

Otherwise Try the following, and see if that helps,

On Windows,

1. [Install Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)
2. [Install PIP](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)
3. Add `python` and `pip` installation path to Windows PATH variable
4. Install Ansible Azure Module: `pip install ansible[azure]`

On CentOS 7.4,

Install `python` and `pip`:

```
sudo yum check-update; sudo yum install -y gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel epel-release

sudo yum install -y python-pip python-wheel
```

Install Ansible Azure Module:

```
sudo pip install ansible[azure]
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,

Install `python` and `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev python-pip
```

Install Ansible Azure Module:

```
sudo pip install ansible[azure]
```