# Error when run Az powershell create Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible, azure-powershell

I create new runbook by ansible-playbook like that

- name: Connect azure account
  command: pwsh -Command "(Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context"

  - name: Create runbook
    command: pwsh -Command "New-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName 'Testing' -Name 'Runbook02' -ResourceGroupName 'hoadtn_ansible_rg' -Type Python3"g

But when I run , it show error
[image]
how to resolve this error ?
thanks

Comment: Could you please try to run `az login`  first , and then try to run the following command for create runbook which you are using.

Comment: I tried to run az login but still error :(

Comment: Have you configured your ansible environment properly. Once can you check `ansible version`

Comment: https://dev.to/cloudskills/connecting-to-azure-with-ansible-22g2 Please refer this and make sure that you have connected Azure with ansible

Comment: Hi, have you tried Ajay's solution, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

***For the above error please make sure that you have updated Ansible version which is `2.9 or above`.***

Then run the command `az login` once successfully run the command then run the following command to create runbook in your azure automation .

We have tried the same and works fine :

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [***Ansible Installation guide***](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/index.html)
- ***SO THREAD:*** [***Ansible install all required Azure modules***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61580507/ansible-install-all-required-azure-modules)